# Calling a method of a different object without breaking encapsulation

Tags: oop, design-patterns, encapsulation

I have an object `GameLogic` which has a `Player` (interface) object.

`GameLogic` has a method `getAvailableMoves()` which is used inside `GameLogic` to let `Player` know about his available moves.

I'm currently implementing an `AIPlayer` (implements `Player`) which should use the Minimax algorithm as a strategy. For that to happen, I want to be able to use `GameLogic`'s `getAvailableMoves()` method from inside `AIPlayer`. However, I'd like to do that without breaking encapsulation. That is to say that I'm trying to avoid passing `GameLogic` as a reference to `Player`.

What is the appropriate solution for this scenario? I assume I should use a Design Pattern but I'm not sure which.

Comment: You would need a service class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to send messages to an object, your object usually needs to have some knowledge of it (unless you want to implement it as an event, which seems awkward). If you're concerned about creating tight coupling between the AIPlayer class and GameLogic, you could create an Interface just for that one method, have GameLogic implement it, and then pass it to the AIPlayer. That way, AIPlayer's only dependency is on the interface, not on the particular GameLogic implementation.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

No need to call getAvailableMoves inside player but from outside and the you can pass player as a parameter in **getAvailableMoves:**

```
class GameWorld {

      main(){  

        GameLogic gl = new GameLogic();
        AIPlayer player = new AIPlayer();
        player.move(gl.getAvailableMoves(player));

    }
}
```

**GameLogic class**

```
 class GameLogic {

         public object getAvailableMoves(Player player){
            player.getX();
            player.getY();

             return availableMoves;
         }
        }
```

**Player class**

```
        class Player{
           float x;
           float y;

        }
```

**AIPlayer class**

```
        class AIPlayer extends Player {
          void move(){

          }

        }
```

**Method 2:**

Also another way is to make getAvailableMoves static and call it from inside player class.

**AIPlayer  class**

```
class AIPlayer extends Player {
          void move(){
              GameLogic.getAvailableMoves(this);
          }

        }
```

**GameLogic  class**

```
class GameLogic {

 public static object getAvailableMoves(Player player){
        player.getX();
        player.getY();

       return availableMoves;
     }
    }
```